# runtime/cgo: could not obtain pthread_keys Simulator Error

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, xcode12

I ran into this issue with Xcode 12.1 simulators running iOS 14.1. My code does compiles then I get the runtime error of

> runtime/cgo: could not obtain pthread_keys
> tried 0x118 0x119 0x11a 0x11b 0x11c 0x11d 0x11e 0x11f 0x120 0x121 0x122 0x123 0x124 0x125 0x126 0x127 0x128 0x129 0x12a 0x12b 0x12c 0x12d 0x12e 0x12f 0x130 0x131 0x132 0x133 0x134 0x135 0x136 0x137 0x138 0x139 0x13a 0x13b 0x13c 0x13d 0x13e 0x13f 0x140 0x141 0x142 0x143 0x144 0x145 0x146 0x147 0x148 0x149 0x14a 0x14b 0x14c 0x14d 0x14e 0x14f 0x150 0x151 0x152 0x153 0x154 0x155 0x156 0x157 0x158 0x159 0x15a 0x15b 0x15c 0x15d 0x15e 0x15f 0x160 0x161 0x162 0x163 0x164 0x165 0x166 0x167 0x168 0x169 0x16a 0x16b 0x16c 0x16d 0x16e 0x16f 0x170 0x171 0x172 0x173 0x174 0x175 0x176 0x177 0x178 0x179 0x17a 0x17b 0x17c 0x17d 0x17e 0x17f 0x180 0x181 0x182 0x183 0x184 0x185 0x186 0x187 0x188 0x189 0x18a 0x18b 0x18c 0x18d 0x18e 0x18f 0x190 0x191 0x192 0x193 0x194 0x195 0x196 0x197

The code runs fine on the iOS 13.5 simulators as well as on a physical device running iOS 14. I would like to have the simulators running and working. Does anyone have a solution for this issue to work on iOS 14 simulators? And if anyone might know if this issue would affect Apple Store submissions

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using a go library framework file with your iOS Project. We had a similar issue with our codebase. To answer your questions:

1. It won't affect Apple Store submissions/releases on the App Store - we have made few releases in the last few months and there have been no issues.
2. Regarding the issue itself, I assume this is because of the go version - you have not stated what go version you are using but this was prevalent if you were using an older version (1.10.x or previous).

Updating your go lib version to a newer release and building your framework file with that version should solve your problem

I haven't understood much on why the issue occurs but here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62784628/9189111) that tries to explain something similar